# Why does a right click open a drop down menu in my OpenCV imshow() window?

Tags: python, opencv, imshow

I am trying to run the [OpenCV Grabcut Sample](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/samples/python/grabcut.py) on my system:

- OpenCV version 4.1.0
- Python version 3.6.8
- IDLE version 3.6.8
- Ubuntu 18.04.2

This is the build information from `cv2.getBuildInformation()`:
[image: build information]

In the Grabcut Sample script, I need to 'draw a rectangle around the object using the **right** mouse button.' For some reason, a drop down menu appears when I click the right mouse button (this is me clicking and holding the right mouse button):

[image: drop down]

This didn't happen before, but since I reformatted my computer and reinstalled OpenCV I get this drop down menu. The `imshow` window looks different too. I tried installing lots of video codec packages ([from this tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2018/05/28/ubuntu-18-04-how-to-install-opencv/)), but that didn't help.

This drop down menu interferes with the mouse callback functions. How can I get rid of this drop down menu?

I installed OpenCV with the command `pip3 install opencv-contrib-python`. I knew I was missing some packages so I tried to install (**but failed - 'couldn't find any package by regex...')** these packages from [this tutorial](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d2/de6/tutorial_py_setup_in_ubuntu.html):

```
sudo apt-get install python-devel numpy
sudo apt-get install gcc gcc-c++
sudo apt-get install gtk2-devel
sudo apt-get install ffmpeg-devel
sudo apt-get install gstreamer-plugins-base-devel
```

Comment: I guess for this kind of problem, you should add details regarding your OS (Ubuntu 18.04?), Python installation, IDE, etc. (And, always you with your fancy animations! :-) )

Comment: That looks like an artifact of the backend used by highgui. That article shows using GTK. Maybe you were using something like Qt before? Anyway, as HansHirse said, we don't have enough information to know for sure.

Comment: @rob3c I added more information about my system. I'm not exactly sure what information I need to add though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the Qt `highgui` backend, which looks like it forces the right-click context menu without the ability to disable it without recompilation of opencv. If you didn't see it before, it's likely you were using a different backend.

If you prefer using Qt and don't mind altering the opencv source slightly and rebuilding, it looks like changing the `DefaultViewPort::contextMenuEvent()` method in file `modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp` to skip building the menu and just returning will probably work (or else have it optionally build the menu due to some flag that you add). Currently, the Qt highgui backend auto-creates the menu using whatever actions are available in the regular menu.

Here's a link to the method in the current opencv master branch as of 2019-06-18:

https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/1d2ef6b2a14fd5f80277d64b14e4a9a2faddc7d8/modules/highgui/src/window_QT.cpp#L2697

which has this code:

```cpp
void DefaultViewPort::contextMenuEvent(QContextMenuEvent* evnt)
{
    if (centralWidget->vect_QActions.size() > 0)
    {
        QMenu menu(this);

        foreach (QAction *a, centralWidget->vect_QActions)
            menu.addAction(a);

        menu.exec(evnt->globalPos());
    }
}
```

An alternative that might work without recompilation might be to use left dragging for selection while checking for an additional modifier key being held down (like shift or ctrl).

I haven't actually tested either of these approaches BTW, so good luck! :-)

UPDATE:
If you still want Qt but don't need the fancy menu options and extra behavior and such, it looks like you can add the `CV_GUI_NORMAL` flag when creating the window to disable the `CV_GUI_EXPANDED` Qt features.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Using a modifier key was the easiest solution. I am now able to accomplish my goal of applying GrabCut to semantic segmentations from DL models: https://imgur.com/a/LdhJHZQ

Comment: That looks like it's working well! Using a modifier key certainly beats a full recompilation :-)

Comment: @StephenMeschke How did you implement the mod key? Would be useful to add some code (Note I have to use right clicks unfortunately: what I do to kill the context menu is have users double click, which cancels out the context menu. It's a hack but works for now).

Answer (score 6):

In Python, you can pass the `cv2.WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL` flag to `namedWindow()` to disable the dropdown (flag is supported only if you have Qt backend):

```py
cv2.namedWindow("window_name", cv2.WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL)
```

And then call

```
cv2.imshow("window_name", img)
```

Link to documentation of the `namedWindow` function is [here](https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/highgui/doc/user_interface.html?highlight=namedwindow#namedwindow).

Answer (score 2):

One additional nuance to above answers. If i just use `cv2.WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL` opencv was showing the original image ignoring the resizing code, but I wanted to see the resized images/frames. So, I restored the other default flags as follows:

```
cv2.namedWindow("window_name", flags=cv2.WINDOW_AUTOSIZE | cv2.WINDOW_KEEPRATIO | cv2.WINDOW_GUI_NORMAL)
```