# Unable to draw on images using namedWindow in Python

Tags: python, opencv

An image opens on running my code in terminal or in Spyder. But there is no action on doing either left or right click. Here is the code I've written:

```py
import cv2
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def drawCircle(event,x,y,flags,param):

    if event == cv2.EVENT_LBUTTONDOWN: #(If Left button of mouse clicked)
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),radius = 100, color =(255,0,0),thickness=-1)
    if event == cv2.EVENT_RBUTTONDOWN: #(If Right button of mouse clicked)
        cv2.circle(img,(x,y),radius = 100, color =(0,255,0),thickness=-1)

img= np.zeros(shape=(512,512,3),dtype=np.int8)
cv2.namedWindow("someimage")

cv2.setMouseCallback("someimage", drawCircle)

while True:
    cv2.imshow("someimage",img)
    if cv2.waitKey(2):
        break

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1):

You're missing an import:

```py
import numpy as np
```

Also, when no key is pressed for the specified delay (2ms in your case), waitkey returns -1. So `cv2.waitKey(2)` call evaluates to a truthy value and `break` is executed. Change it to

```py
if cv2.waitKey(2) == ord("q"):
    break
```

This will stop the loop only when you press key `q`

I also noticed that right clicking will open a context menu first. Here is the link to the solution:
[Why does a right click open a drop down menu in my OpenCV imshow() window?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61840993/11389917)

Comment: Wow i just added that check ==ord("q") and now my left click makes a blue circle and right click make a green circle, and on pressing q, my window got closed. Brilliant. Thanks for the help. Btw, Right click is not creating context click problem for me.